# Forcing a compiler to state whether method has been implemented - C++

Tags: c++

if I have the following code:

```
class A
{
public:
        virtual void Yo();
}

class B : public A
{   
    public:
        virtual void Yo() override;
}
```

**Is there a way to force B to implement method Yo in A**? Like an interface or more specifically (in this case) an abstract?

---

My full code is here:

**BaseObject.h**

```
#pragma once

namespace Game
{
    namespace Model
    {
        namespace Graphic
        {
            class BaseObject
            {
            public:
                int Width;
                int Height;
                float X;
                float Y;
                float Z;

                virtual void SetUp() = 0;
                virtual void Reset() = 0;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**Player.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"

#include "Abstract\BaseObject.h"

using namespace Game::Model::Graphic;

class Player : public BaseObject
{
public:
    Player();
    ~Player();

    //virtual void SetUp();
    //virtual void Reset() override;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

in `A` make `Yo` pure virtual

```
virtual void Yo() = 0;
```

---

a complete example

```
#include <iostream>
struct A
{
    virtual void Yo() = 0;
};
struct B : A
{
    virtual void Yo() { std::cout << "I'm B\n"; }
};
int main()
{
    B b;
    b.Yo();
    return (0);
}
```

if `B` doesn't implement `Yo` this will not compile.

The `override` keyword it's not needed in this case.

Comment: I have already tried this and it doesn't force on compilation, im using VS2013. any ideas why that might be?

Comment: The compilation will fail whenever you try to create a new instance of class A or derived class that does not implement all pure virtual methods of A.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 that's how to do it in `C++`, `override` it's not a `C++` keyword, if you are using compiler specific keywords refer to the official documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41w3sh1c.aspx

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 in a nutshell just don't use `override`.

Comment: @user2485710, override is a C++11 keyword.

Comment: How odd, I wonder if it's something to do with it being a class library?

Comment: @Jefffrey not in pre C++11 implementations .

Comment: @Jimmyt1988, the compiler won't force B to implement A, because if B does not implement Yo, it is still abstract class.

Comment: @user2485710, C++11 is currently offical C++ standard. VS2013 supports override syntax, afaik.

Comment: @user2485710, it's 2014, we can safely assume C++11 to be available for every user, unless specified otherwise.

Comment: `override` is not a C++ keyword. See C++11 [lex.name] . It is an identifier that has a special meaning in the context that OP used it, in other situations it is nothing special. You can write `int override = 1;` etc.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 - as I said, try "new Player()", the compiler just won't let you do that.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988, you might also try C++11 keyword "final", but idk if VS2013 supports it or not.

Comment: @Garrappachc, `final` means that no class can override the method, he wants it to cause an error if a class does notoverrides the method

Comment: @Jefffrey I don't think that VS is even near to implement C++11 in a decent way, probably with VS is better to stick with C++03. Anyway I think that `override` will not solve anything here.

Comment: @awesomeyi - not if used like "class Foo final {};"

Comment: @user2485710: re "the override keyword is not needed in this case", first it's not a keyword but a context-dependent special identifier (along with final, which is the other one), and secondly, "override" is never technically needed, just as e.g. for-loops are never technically needed. just use labels and goto. that's a good programmer.

Comment: @user2485710 - you can see which of C++11 features are supported

Comment: Are we gonna debate the entire C++ standard for something that can be solved with a `= 0` ? C++ it's not Java, don't try to code it like it's a Java ancestor. You are right about the fact that `override` it's not a keyword, and maybe `C++11` should be promoted to a new level, but Windows it's not exactly cutting edge as far as C++ goes, and if we are going to debate how virtual / final / override work, we are gonna need something like 3-4 wikipedia articles.

Comment: @user2485710 - I'm not talking about using variadic templates or lambdas, its just "override". Its good custom to use that to make sure your definitions are correct and mark overriding methods. Whats more, if your compiler does not support override syntax, just can just use #define to get rid of that, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take `pointer of the base class` to implement `virtual functions` in C++. This seems quite obvious. But i think we have missed that. The most basic example is given below.

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class base {
         public:
            virtual void vfunc() {
                cout << "This is base's vfunc().\n";
             }
    };
     class derived1 : public base {
          public:
                void vfunc() {
                     cout << "This is derived1's vfunc().\n";
        }
    };
    int main()
    {
         base *p, b;
         derived1 d1;
         // point to base
         p = &b;
         p->vfunc(); // access base's vfunc()
         // point to derived1
         p = &d1;
         p->vfunc(); // access derived1's vfunc()
         return 0;
    }
```